# .htaccess specific relocation

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got troubles with .htaccess, I know there are similar posts, but I cant figure out even with them.

I need my webpage to relocate user from url like
website.net/photos?action=something
to
website.net/?fotky=something

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^photos$  ?fotky=%2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: whole .htaccess looks like this: `<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC] 
RerwiteRule ^photos$  ?fotky=%2 [L,R=301]`

Comment: try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` before that

Comment: @UlrichPalha Thanks, works now.

yoavmatchulsky That was not needed, but thanks for your effort.